# Approximation for $\prod\limits_{r<p\le P}\left( 1-\frac rp\right)^{-1}$

Tags: prime-numbers, euler-product

> Is there an approximation for $\prod\limits_{r<p\le P}\left( 1-\frac rp\right)^{-1}$ when $r$ is fix and greater than $1$ and $p$ is prime

For example if $r=1$ then the above is approximately $\log(P)$

Can we say something like $\log(P)^r$ ?

Comment: Here $p$ stands for a prime or just an integer?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio $p$ is prime

Comment: If you know how $\prod_{r\leq p\leq P}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^{-1}$ behaves, you may simply approximate $\left(1-\frac{r}{p}\right)^{-1}$ with $\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^{-r}$. So, sure, something like $\log(P)^r$.

Comment: Intuitively, the answer should be $log(\frac{p}{r})$, because we can simplify the product into $\prod\limits_{1<p/r \le P/r}\left( 1-\frac {1}{(\frac pr)}\right)^{-1} \approx \prod\limits_{1<q \le P/r}\left( 1-\frac {1}{q} \right)^{-1} \approx log (\frac Pr).$